# Flutter: BottomNavigationBarItem with CachedNetworkImageProvider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

how to get BottomNavigationBarItem to load CachedNetworkImageProvider

[image]

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
 icon: Icon(
   CachedNetworkImageProvider(ub.imageUrl)
 ),
 title: Text('Profile'),
),
```

error occurred : 'The argument type CachedNetworkImageProvider can't be assigned to parameters type of IconData'

Comment: Try to get rid of the Icon..

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Image` widget in place of the Icon and then provide the `CachedNetworkImageProvider` in the Image widget itself.